# Angular 2.0.2: ActivatedRoute is empty in a Service

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to use ActivatedRoute to get route params in a service like I would do in a Component.
However, when I inject the ActivatedRoute object in a Service it contains an empty params variable

I've created a plunker that reproduces the behaviour:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sckmDYnpIlZUbqqB3gli

Note that the intention is to use the parameter in the service and not in the component, the way the plunker is set up is purely to demonstrate the issue.

Component (`test` is retrieved):

```ts
export class Component implements OnInit {
  result: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.result = params['test'];
    });
  }
}
```

Service (`test` is **not** retrieved):

```ts
export class Service {
  result: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.result = params['test'];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it is a good idea to inject route into a service. `Service` is a singleton. `ActivatedRoute` is not. I guess that `ActivatedRoute` instances are just different in Component and Service.

Comment: @estus Makes sense, I could pass the param to the service via a function. But this seems clunky.

Comment: I used an rxjs `ReplaySubject` to store/observe the required values. Felt like a simple solution at least for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74254741/3370568

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Service` here is a singleton that belongs to root injector and is injected with [root `ActivatedRoute` instance](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.2/modules/%40angular/router/src/router_module.ts#L60).

Outlets get their own injector and [own `ActivatedRoute` instance](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.2/modules/%40angular/router/src/router.ts#L939-L956).

[The solution here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LZqV7ilCx2A3KM561qj?p=preview) is to let route components have their own `Service` instances:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [Service]
})
export class MainComponent { ... }
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution but creating multiple singleton services has its downsides. For example, if this service performs a http request and then caches the result it would do so for every service instance

Comment: Then they should be two different services, I guess. The one is singleton, another one is specific to current route. The whole pattern was pretty much the same in Angular 1. If you have some real-world design issue, feel free to update the question with the context.

Comment: Well, you solved the issue I described here so I'll keep it as it is. I'll figure out if splitting the service up will do the trick and create a new issue when it does not. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Creating a singleton is also not possible if the sole purpose of the service is to keep specific state across multiple components (using the url as the single source of truth).

Answer (score 18):

The [answer of estus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980190/531122) provides a good solution when multiple service instances are not an issue.

The following solution gets a parameter straight from the router and allows the service to have one instance:

```js
export class Service {
  result: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.result = router.routerState.snapshot.root.children[0].url[index].path
  }
}
```

or as an observable:

```js
export class Service {
  result: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.routerState.root.children[0].url.map((url) => {
      this.result = url[index].path;
    });
  }
}
```

alternatively, when routerState is not available:

```js
export class Service {
  result: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).root.children.primary.segments[index].toString();
  }
}
```

Index is the position of the param in the url.

Comment: Is there a way to unit test the service with RouterTestingModule when using this approach? router.routerState.snapshot.root.children is empty by default in the injected Router.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue and the working solution I end with is the following.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample',
  styleUrls: [`../sample.component.scss`],
  templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
})
export class AppSampleComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private someService: SomeService){}
  public callServiceAndProcessRoute(): void {
    this.someService.processRoute(route);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  public processRoute(route: ActivatedRoute): void {
  // do stuff with route
  }
}
```

So you will pass the `ActivatedRoute` to the service as a param.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following code from the Angular documentation (as of 2022) which suggests to use the following code in a service:

> You can compute all params (or data) in the router state or to get params outside of an activated component by traversing the `RouterState` tree as in the following  example:

```
collectRouteParams(router: Router) {
    let params = {};
    let stack: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[] = [router.routerState.snapshot.root];
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        const route = stack.pop()!;
        params = {...params, ...route.params};
        stack.push(...route.children);
    }
    return params;
}
```

See also the discussion here and related issues: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/40306

Comment: "outside of an activated component" and therefore suitable for a service... 

Answer (score -3):

I can't see a `routerLink` directive in your Plunker code you provided.

You need to use a `routerLink` directive to navigate to your component, where you supply the param, then only you can retrieve it. For example:

```
<a routerLink="/myparam" >Click here to go to main component</a>
```

Comment: The plunker redirects to `/success` which is then retrieved, there is no need for an extra navigation