# How to get the current route params on route changes in a component not loaded by the router

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to get the params from a route that looks like "/categories/:cat1/:cat2/browse"

getting it in the component loaded by the route seems to work fine, but another component that is already loaded in the app that isn't changed by route changes

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumbs',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumbs.component.scss'],
})
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(e => {
      activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        console.log({ params });
      });
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up fixing this was:

1) Create a breadcrumb service which usies BehaviorSubject to receive updates for params

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { BreadcrumbsList } from './breadcrumbsList';
import { ParseErrorLevel } from '@angular/compiler';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047854/how-to-update-a-component-without-refreshing-full-page-angular
export class BreadcrumbsService {
  public breadcrumbsList: BehaviorSubject<BreadcrumbsList> = new BehaviorSubject({
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': 'BreadcrumbList',
    itemListElement: []
  });

  constructor() {}

  // https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumb#example
  updateParamMap(paramMap, root, suffix = null, endpoint = null) {
    const breadcrumbsList = {
      '@context': 'https://schema.org',
      '@type': 'BreadcrumbList',
      itemListElement: []
    };
    let position = 0;
    let curPath = '';
    console.log({ test: paramMap.get('level1') });
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      let level = paramMap.get('level' + i);
      if (i === 0) {
        level = root;
      }
      if (!level) {
        continue;
      }
      curPath += '/' + level;
      let item = {
        '@type': 'ListItem',
        position: i + 1,
        name: level,
        item: suffix ? curPath + '/' + suffix : curPath
      };
      breadcrumbsList.itemListElement.push(item);
    }
    if (endpoint) {
      let item = {
        '@type': 'ListItem',
        position: i + 2,
        name: endpoint
      };
      breadcrumbsList.itemListElement.push(item);
    }
    // update the breadcrumbs list for anything that is listening for updates
    this.breadcrumbsList.next(breadcrumbsList);
  }
}
```

2) In each component that is loaded up by a route that should update the breadcrumbs, import the BreadcrumbService, and add this line to the `ngOnInit()`

```
this.breadcrumbsService.updateParamMap(this.route.snapshot.paramMap, 'assets', 'browse');
```

3) In the breadcrumb component, have the breadcrumbsList subscribe to updates from the BreadcrumbsService

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BreadcrumbsList } from './breadcrumbsList';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-breadcrumbs',
  templateUrl: './breadcrumbs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./breadcrumbs.component.scss']
})
export class BreadcrumbsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() path: String[];
  breadcrumbsList: BreadcrumbsList;

  constructor(breadcrumbsService: BreadcrumbsService) {
    breadcrumbsService.breadcrumbsList.subscribe(value => {
      this.breadcrumbsList = value;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

And the breadcrumb template can handle the BreadcrumbsList

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to be subscribing to route params instead of query params. (i.e. activatedRoute.params.subscribe instead of activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe)

Comment: Yep, good call Kyle. I fixed that detail in the question, but still params ends up being an empty object.

Comment: It looks like we may be dealing with two different instances of the activated route, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977962/angular-2-0-2-activatedroute-is-empty-in-a-service).  There are some potential solutions in that post, but none of them as clean as you'd expect.