# How can a service subscribe to the ParamMap of the current route?

Tags: angular, router, angular-activatedroute

I would like to create a service that subscribes to changes in Angular's paramMap. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

```
export class LocationResourcesService {

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map((params: ParamMap) => params.get('account-id')),
    ).subscribe((newValue) => console.log(newValue))
  }
  // ----------
}
```

Tthe subscription above only ever emits one value - when Angular first loads into the page. And that value is `null`. The same subscription does when it's placed in the constructor of a component that's active in the page. presumably because the route has loaded and the `ActivatedRoute` has been set.

I would have assumed that ActivatedRoute was a singleton service and that I could therefore subscribe to changes on it. Obviously that's not the case though so how can this service subscribe to the value of `activatedRoute.ParamMap`?

Comment: Does your router correctly analyzes the route? try the `enableTracing` option and see if the `account-id` param appears when you navigate to the relevant route.

Answer (score 2):

There's unfortunately no easy answer to this. I'm not going to reproduce the whole discussion but the solution can be seen here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11023#issuecomment-399667101.

And I'm copying it across to make it easy to get a feel for it. As I said, it's not straightforward:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class MiscService {

  params$: Observable<Params>

  constructor( private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    // Create an observable representing the params
    this.params$ = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      switchMap(() => {
        const params = this.route.firstChild?.params
        // return params or an empty observable 
        return params || of()
      })
    )
    
    // subscribe to the params$ observable - can be done for 
    // multiple observers
    this.params$.subscribe((params) => {
      console.log('params', params)
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (Pure RxJS implementation using [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject)):

The common service where the param (eg. `paramThing`) will be stored (as an observable):

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class MyService {
  // use ReplaySubject to store/observe the paramThing
  paramThing$ = new ReplaySubject<string | null>(1);

  constructor() {}
}
```

Then in the component where `ActivatedRoute` **gives proper value**:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-xxx",
  templateUrl: "./xxx.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./xxx.component.scss"],
})
export class XxxComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subs: Subscription[] = [];
  constructor(
    private readonly actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private readonly myService: DashService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const subscription = this.actRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map((parameters) => parameters.get("paramThing")))
      .subscribe((paramThingValue) => {
        this.myService.paramThing$.next(paramThingValue); // <=== this does the trick
      });
    this.subs.push(subscription);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    for (const item of this.subs) item.unsubscribe();
    this.subs = [];
    // if you need, you can unset the value when component goes out of scope
    this.myService.paramThing$.next(null);
  }
}
```

Then in any consuming component/service, you can use the `MyService` to get the value of paramThing:

Example service where I need the `paramThing`.

```
import { lastValueFrom, take, switchMap } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-ccc",
  templateUrl: "./ccc.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./ccc.component.scss"],
})
export class CccComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private readonly myService: MyService
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const paramThing = await lastValueFrom(this.myService.paramThing$.pipe(take(1)));
    // paramThing:null | string
    
    // or if you want an observable chain for paramThing
    this.myService.paramThing$.pipe(
      switchMap(paramThing => {
        return anotherPromiseOrObservableChain;
      }),
      // ...
    ).subscribe(...)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Peter Nixey did not work for me unless I injected the ActivatedRoute service into the component I wanted to subscribe to the changes. While the solution of Wajahath works, it is hacky because you need to inject from a component to a service before being able to use the value.

I propose the following solution. It includes getting the current route params, an observable to all route params changes and an observable for a specific route param change (by param name).

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class ParamsService {

    /**
     * The route params.
     */
    readonly routeParams$: Observable<Params> = this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    ).pipe(
        map(_ => this.getCurrentRouteParams()),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
    );

    /**
     * Gets the observable of a specific route param.
     */
    routeParamByName(paramName: string, defaultValue: string): Observable<T> {
        return this.routeParams$.pipe(
            map(params => params[paramName] ?? defaultValue),        
            distinctUntilChanged(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current params in the activated route.
     * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977962/angular-2-0-2-activatedroute-is-empty-in-a-service/74915199#74915199
     */
    getCurrentRouteParams(): Params {

        let params: any = {};
        let stack: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[] = [this.router.routerState.snapshot.root];

        while (stack.length > 0) {
            const route = stack.pop()!;
            params = {...params, ...route.params};
            stack.push(...route.children);
        }

        return params;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to do something at the change of a specific parameter on your route...

Try to plug a [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) in the app-routing.module.ts
You can create it with : "ng g r TheThingYouWantToDo"

Less harder than you think :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35694160)

Comment: @RicardoGellman It doesn't because the way Angular preconise to do is to use the routing lifecycle when you want to do something with your Route.
Service will do the stuff but so late compared to resolver, so the fact is that the need can be simplified, just by using a different tool that is more appropriate for thoses stuffs.